# how to set a checkbox if the value from the DB is true and uncheck if the value is false on edit in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to auto set a checkbox base on the value in the DB 1 or 0 
which is returning true or false in my controller
how can I  auto check a checkbox base on the value from the DB . i.e check if true and uncheck if false
this is the angularJS code

```
$http.get('/api/cusEmoAllo/' + $routeParams.EmpID).success(function (data)
    {
        //data[0].taxS);  this may true or false // check if true uncheck if false
        $scope.box = data[0].taxS;
    });
```

this is the checkbox

```
 <input id="box" type="checkbox" ng-model="box" />
```

I am new in angular, thanks!!

Comment: You have done right, it should be working...there must be some other problem...can you please provide code in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<input id="box" type="checkbox" ng-model="box">
```

> $scope.box should be boolean true/false , not String "true"/"false"

you can check the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bc4wqy5z/)

For more details check [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

Comment: this is not working. I mean I want to auto check base on the value from the DB on edit

Comment: @LLJanneh :  I have create a jsfiddle example , you can check that